# Split a string which is inside a list of a list in two elements which stay in the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int, tuples

This is a chain of number inside a text file which I import and want to convert into a specific list.

```
3 04,24
4 04,75
4 05,11
4 05,47
4 05,78
4 06,80
3 07,25
3 07,92
3 08,23
2 09,76
```

Actually with my code I reach this point :

```
[['3 04,24'], ['4 04,75'], ['4 05,11'], ['4 05,47'], ['4 05,78'], ['4 06,80'], ['3 07,25'], ['3 07,92'], ['3 08,23'], ['2 09,76']]
```

But I want to split the elements inside the tuples in two to get something like this :

```
[['3','04,24'], ['4','04,75']] etc...
```

But after many research I can't find the solution, also if you could tell me how to convert these elements from string to int that would be very helpful !

Here's my code :

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    mylist = [mylist[x:x+1] for x in range(0, len(mylist), 1)]
    print(mylist)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution using `csv` module from the standard library:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    res = list(reader)
```

Example with your data:-

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""3 04,24
4 04,75
4 05,11
4 05,47
4 05,78
4 06,80
3 07,25
3 07,92
3 08,23
2 09,76""")

with mystr as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    res = list(reader)

print(res)

# [['3', '04,24'],
#  ['4', '04,75'],
#  ['4', '05,11'],
#  ['4', '05,47'],
#  ['4', '05,78'],
#  ['4', '06,80'],
#  ['3', '07,25'],
#  ['3', '07,92'],
#  ['3', '08,23'],
#  ['2', '09,76']]
```

Or if you need to convert data to numeric:

```
with mystr as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    res = [[int(i), float(j.replace(',', '.'))] for i, j in reader]

print(res)

[[3, 4.24],
 [4, 4.75],
 [4, 5.11],
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [['3 04.24'], ['4 04.75'], ['4 05.11'], ['4 05.47'], ['4 05.78'], ['4 06.80'], ['3 07.25'], ['3 07.92'], ['3 08.23'], ['2 09.76']]
>>> [x[0].split() for x in lst]
```

Outputs:

```
[['3', '04.24'], 
 ['4', '04.75'], 
 ['4', '05.11'], 
 ['4', '05.47'], 
 ['4', '05.78'], 
 ['4', '06.80'], 
 ['3', '07.25'], 
 ['3', '07.92'], 
 ['3', '08.23'], 
 ['2', '09.76']]
```

To convert string into integer:

```
[[int(i) if not '.' in i else float(i) for i in x[0].split()] for x in lst]
```

Comment: It also works but how do I convert these strings chain into int ?

Comment: I have converted every second number with a dot, that would be easier I think.

Comment: Thanks so I will use to differents lists one with the first number and an other one with the second number.

Comment: What I wanted looks like jpp's solution but you were also really helpful, ty !

Comment: Ok, that's fine.  Just a reminder: you are not having any tuples here like your title says. This is a list of lists.

Comment: Okay I'm new to python and I though that a list into a list was called a tuple.

Comment: `()` identifies a tuple and `[]` is a list.

Comment: But in my case, will tuple change anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str.split()` method:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    my_structured_list = [line.split(" ") for line in mylist]

    print(my_structured_list)
```

For the second part of your question about converting the elements to int, you can use `str.split()` again and convert the resulting elements to `int`:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    my_structured_list = [line.split(" ") for line in mylist]

    my_structured_int_list = []
    for line_tuple in my_structured_list:
        input_first_element = line_tuple[0]
        input_second_element, input_third_element = line_tuple[1].split(",")

        output_first_half = int(input_first_element)
        output_second_half = int(input_second_element), int(input_third_element)

        my_structured_int_list.append((output_first_half, output_second_half))

    print(my_structured_int_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is as follows

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    print([each.split() for each in f])
```